# could not open proj generic class cache for build file flutter

Tags: flutter, exception, build

OR
failure build failed with an exception. in flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DstvE.png)

PS F:\flutter project> flutter clean
PS F:\flutter project> flutter upgrade

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBuxW.png)

version change 7.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z4Am.png)

Pub get

finally project run error gone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal type
PS F:\flutter project> flutter clean
PS F:\flutter project> flutter upgrade

version change 7.6

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
pubspec.yaml
Pub get
and project run
error gone